# Docker run failing after startup (node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

After running `docker build . -t app`, once I run `docker run -p 8080:8080 app`, either the Docker container or node is throwing an error preventing me from viewing my app. Whenever I run my node app locally, I usually just run `npm run dev` and everything works fine. I've tried changing the node versions within my `Dockerfile`, cleaning the npm cache, running different commands, etc. Nothing seems to work, but I think this error is caused by some port issue since I see the same thing when I try running the app within my EC2 server.

Here's the output that's where I am seeing the issue

```sh
user@MacBook-Pro-2 Website % docker run -p 8080:8080 app

> permitivity@1.0.0 dev /usr/src/app
> node build/dev-server.js

> Starting dev server...
{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 18640ms2:44:03 AM

> Listening at http://localhost:8080

(node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/opn/index.js:85:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12)
(node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My Dockerfile is quite simply:

```sh
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile. Try to change your app to listen on '0.0.0.0' instead of localhost.

Comment: Try running `COPY . .` before running `npm install`. Currently, when you copy all files after the installation of the modules, you will overwrite the `node_modules` that ware installed with the one on your build environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened is that in my `dev-server.js`, after the port is opened, the server tries to open the url in the browser. Obviously, this doesn't work within a docker container and so the process crashes.

```js
devMiddleware.waitUntilValid(() => {
  console.log('> Listening at ' + uri + '\n')
  // when env is testing, don't need open it
  if (autoOpenBrowser && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing') {
    opn(uri)
  }
  _resolve()
})
```

All I did to fix this is to comment out `opn(uri)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the docker port to the host by adding 1 line in the end of Dockerfile;

**EXPOSE 8080**

Also write full command as **RUN npm install**. It's probably due to packages.